# C# - Get LastWriteTime of A Folder's Descendants

Tags: c#, file-io, directory

How can I retrieve the latest write time of **any** descendant of a folder?

I need a method that will return the paths of all files that were modified after a specified DateTime. I figured I could save a lot of expensive disk reading by making sure the directory [LastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx) is within the specified range before going through the trouble of iterating through its files and subdirectories.

This works in that when a file within the top level of a directory changes, the last write time of the folder is updated as well. However, the last write time does not bubble up any further than the file's immediate parent. In other words, if the grandchild file is changed, its property is updated, and so is it's father folder's, but not the grandfather.

Is there another high-level indicator I can use to accomplish this, or will I have to resort to recursing through every folder regardless of last change time?

Here is the method as it currently stands:

```
private void AddAllFilesOfAllSubdirsWithFilterToList(string dirPath, ref List<FileInfo> filesList, DateTime minDate)
{
    // Return files in this directory level
    foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc > minDate)
        {
            filesList.Add(fileInfo);
        }
    }

    // Return recursive searches through sudirs
    foreach (string subDirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath))
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(subDirPath);
        if (dirInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc > minDate)
        {
            GetAllFilesOfAllSubdirsWithFilter(subDirPath, ref filesList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You claim that changing a file updates the directory's LastWriteTime, but I just tested this on Windows 10 and on MacOS 11 and I did not see that. I changed a file but the directory's last write time remained unchanged.

Comment: I have confirmed too, the lastwritetime updates on file creation, but it does not update when a file is modified. This very regrettable design decision means the right answer is to iterate over all files to catch modifications based on the individual file lastwritetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to say but I think you will have to go through all subdirectories.

Just change your SearchOption from your code above to recurse through subdirectories...

```
private void AddAllFilesOfAllSubdirsWithFilterToList(string dirPath, ref List<FileInfo> filesList, DateTime minDate)
{
    // I'm assuming you want to clear this here... I would generally return it 
    //   instead of passing it as ref
    filesList.Clear();

    // Return all files in directory tree
    foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc > minDate)
        {
            filesList.Add(fileInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. It's what I had been doing previously; the call to GetFiles with the AllDirectories parameter is **extremely** slow iterating over all the files in all the subdirectories, returning a 10,000-item list, of which maybe only 2 will pass the DateTime check.

Comment: One thing you could do is check the LastWriteTime on the directories and then only search for files in those directories.  I'm not sure if that would be significantly faster or not but it's at least something to try.

Comment: Aldo, I'm passing by ref so I can modify one collection pointer instead of adding/re-creating at every recursion, but generally, yes, I prefer to follow functional programming: return a value and change no parameters.

Comment: Note: the directory LastWriteTime is not updated when a file is merely updated. If a file is created then indeed the directory LastWriteTime is updated. This seems like a filesystem or OS bug.

Answer (score 1):

**You** don't have to recurse through the directory tree. The CLR is perfectly happy to do it for you.

```
public FileInfo[] RecentlyWrittenFilesWithin( string path , string searchPattern , DateTime dateFrom , DateTime dateThru )
{
  if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( path ) ) {  throw new ArgumentException("invalid path" , "path" );}
  DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(path) ;
  if ( !root.Exists ) {  throw new ArgumentException( "non-existent directory" , "path" ) ; }
  bool isDirectory = FileAttributes.Directory == ( FileAttributes.Directory & root.Attributes ) ;
  if ( isDirectory ) {  throw new ArgumentException("not a directory","path");}

  FileInfo[] files = root.EnumerateFiles( searchPattern , SearchOption.AllDirectories )
                         .Where( fi => fi.LastWriteTime >= dateFrom && fi.LastWriteTime <= dateThru )
                         .ToArray()
                         ;
  return files ;
}
```

Depending on the context here (for instance, if you program is a a service of some sort),  you could establish a `FileSystemWatcher` on your root directory and monitor changes as they occur.